# Use a variable in xlPivotFilter type

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivot table with `Date` as a pivot field.  I'd like to add a pivot filter with `Type=xlAllDatesInPeriodJanuary`, however I don't want to hardcode which period I filter to.  I'm not sure if this is possible in VBA, but can I use a variable and concatenate that pivot filter type?
Let's say the month I want is entered in `Sheet2`, cell `A1`.
I know this won't work, but I'd like to do something to the effect of:

```
Dim month As String

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable

month = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

PvtTbl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1") 

PvtTbl.ClearAllFilters 

PvtTbl.PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add Type="xlAllDatesInPeriod" & month
```

That way, the pivot table automatically filters to whatever month is typed into `Sheet2`, `A1`.
If this isn't possible, I could code 12 `If` statements which read the names of the months and code `Type=xlAllDatesInPeriodJanuary/February/March/etc`, but only if that's the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary` to create the enumeration. The values for `xlAllDatesInPeriodJanuary` through `xlAllDatesInPeriodDecember` are `57` through `68`, so add strings representing the name of the enumeration and the value:

```
Dim d As Object, i As Long
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 1 To 12
    d.Add "xlAllDatesInPeriod" & MonthName(i), 56 + i
Next
```

Then you can use your dictionary, `d`, to retrieve the proper value based on the string key:

```
PvtTbl.PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add Type:=d("xlAllDatesInPeriod" & month)
```

If you stored your `month` as an integer instead (`1 - 12`), you could forget all about the dictionary and just use the following:

```
PvtTbl.PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add Type:=(xlAllDatesInPeriodJanuary + month - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Bond, your second suggestion worked easily.  When trying your first suggestion with creating a dictionary, I got an error on the line creating the scripting.dictionary : "429: ActiveX component can't create object" 
Any idea how to fix that? It seems that a dictionary could be useful in other problems as well.